# How to keep once changed data value on select options?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$('.sela').change(function(){
  var obj = $('.sela:visible');
  var uname = obj.find(':selected').data('x');
  $('#inptest').val(uname);
})

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').attr('data-x', 999)
  var a = $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').attr('data-x')
  $('#inptest').val(a);
});
```

```css
#btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option value='lorem1' data-x='left'>ADMIN</option>
<option value='lorem2' data-x='right'>AUTHS</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='sela'>
<option value='lorem3' data-x='up'>SKY</option>
<option value='lorem4' data-x='down'>EARTH</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type='text' id='inptest'value='323'>
<br><br>
<div id='btn'>BUTTON</div>
```

Change first `sela` to `AUTHS`.
`inptest` becomes `right`
Click on `btn` - `sela` selected option data-x is `999` and `inptest` is `999`
Now change `sela` back to `ADMIN` and again to `AUTH`.
I'm expecting it to keep `999` but it becomes `right`.
How to keep once changed data value on `sela` options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be consistent,

either use `.attr('data-x')`/`.attr('data-x', newValue)` or use `.data('x')`/`.data('x',newValue)`

So

```js
$('.sela').change(function() {
  var obj = $('.sela:visible');
  var uname = obj.find(':selected').data('x');
  $('#inptest').val(uname);
})

$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').data('x', 999)
  var a = $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').data('x')
  $('#inptest').val(a);
});
```

```css
#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
  <option value='lorem1' data-x='left'>ADMIN</option>
  <option value='lorem2' data-x='right'>AUTHS</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='sela'>
  <option value='lorem3' data-x='up'>SKY</option>
  <option value='lorem4' data-x='down'>EARTH</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type='text' id='inptest' value='323'>
<br><br>
<div id='btn'>BUTTON</div>
```

Or

```js
$('.sela').change(function(){
  var obj = $('.sela:visible');
  var uname = obj.find(':selected').attr('data-x');
  $('#inptest').val(uname);
})

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').attr('data-x', 999)
  var a = $('.sela:visible').find(':selected').attr('data-x')
  $('#inptest').val(a);
});
```

```css
#btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option value='lorem1' data-x='left'>ADMIN</option>
<option value='lorem2' data-x='right'>AUTHS</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='sela'>
<option value='lorem3' data-x='up'>SKY</option>
<option value='lorem4' data-x='down'>EARTH</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type='text' id='inptest'value='323'>
<br><br>
<div id='btn'>BUTTON</div>
```

Comment: @AjAX. read http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5
**The `data-` attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated *(all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)***.